# Remap f keys for chromebook running linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, chromebook

I installed arch Linux on my Chromebook and I'm using LXDE. I looked into re-mapping the search key/caps lock key to the super/windows key and was able to do that with "setxkbmap -option caps:super" Now I want to do the same for the F keys. I've tried doing the same thing but I don't thing xkb supports F keys. I want the layout to go like this

`ESC
HOME
END
F5
F11
Any suggestions?
brightness up
brightness down (I'm using xbacklight -dec/inc 20)
mute
volume up
volume down
power`

[image: Chromebok keys]

And I want to be able to use them as normal F keys when holding the Search/Capslock (Now mapped to super (This is going to get confusing :))

Comment: Check out [Xbindkeys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys).

Comment: @vesche It can run commands but I can't figure out how to output home, end, and F keys